# Consequence of Hadamard directional derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

Let $F:H \to H$ be a Hadamard differentiable function on a Hilbert space $H$, meaning that the following limit exists:

$$\lim_{t \to 0\\ \hat h \to h}\frac{F(x+t\hat h)-F(x)}{t} = F'(x)(h).$$

I read somewhere that if $F$ is Hadamard differentiable, then the following also holds: if $h(t) \to h$ as $t \to 0$, then
$$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{F(x+th(t))-F(x)}{t} = F'(x)(h).$$

Can someone show me to how to prove this? The problem is that there is a $t$ dependence in $h(t)$ that I don't see how to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  see that whole fraction as a function in terms of $(t,h)$, say $f(t,h)$. If first limit exists then all limit on paths  exist too! Including the path$(t, h(t) )$